# AVFoundation cannot read wav file format

Tags: audio, avfoundation, wav, avassetwriter, avasset

I'm trying to create a wav file from multiple other wav files.
I use AVAsset, AVAssestReader and AVAssetWriter.

The format setting used for the `AVAssetWriterInput` and `AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput` is created like this:
`AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: true)`

And the AVAssetWriter is created like this: `AVAssetWriter(url: outputURL, fileType: .wav)`

Btw I noticed 2 weirds things:

**1)** When I create an AVAsset from a wav file I haven't any metadta.
The asset creation is:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: mWaveFilePath)
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
```

I cannot do simpler, and when I look for metadata properties of this asset I get always empty array with wav file...

**2)** The most important is when I write a wave file I've the feelling that AVFoundation makes some errors in the [wave header](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/). Maybe it comes from me but I manage to create a wave file with audio, and followed some tutorial I've a bad time for finding where the error could come from.
Here is an example of good an and bad header:

The good header before importing the file.
[image]
We can see that the format tag is set to 1 which mean PCM. That's what we want.

Now the wrong header after the creation of my audio file:
[image]
-2... It's clearly wrong.

So did I miss something on using AVFoundation for creating a wav file, should I do something special?

Comment: That Wave header isn't "bad". What's being displayed as a `signed short -2` is actually the value for the `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` format, whereas the value of `1` in your "good" header is `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM`. How to get AVFoundation to create a file in the latter format is something I'm [also currently trying to figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990855/can-avassetwriter-be-used-to-write-a-wave-format-pcm-wave-file).

Comment: @Rich Thanks for your input and the precision. I didn't know that. Unfortunately I didn't find any better solution than changing this field manually in my code...